# How do I update DatabaseDataSet using TableAdapter?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I'm using Visual C# Studio 2010 express and have been trying to batch update my table. Everytime that I try to update 1 record I get "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."  I asked this question at dream in code but I have been a little dissapointed in some of the responses to some honest questions. [Link to my question at D.I.C](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/274690-concurrency-violation-while-trying-to-update-database/)

I took that last suggestions and changed my code to affect the dataset..or so I think but i am getting the concurrent issue still. Here is my updated code.

```
        private void SendNewPotentialsToZoho()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to send potentials to Zoho");

        var newZoho = potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential.DefaultView;
        var poster = new ZohoPoster(ZohoPoster.Fields.Potentials, ZohoPoster.Calls.insertRecords);
        var count = 0;

        //newZoho.RowFilter = "IsNull(ZohoID,'zoho') = 'zoho'";
        newZoho.RowFilter = "Soid = 1234";
        poster.Debugging = !UseZoho;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)//newZoho.Count; i++)
        {
            var xmlString = Potential.GetPotentialXML(newZoho[i][1], newZoho[i][2], newZoho[i][4], newZoho[i][3], newZoho[i][5], newZoho[i][7], newZoho[i][0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending New Records to Zoho: {0}", xmlString);
            poster.PostItem.Set("xmlData", xmlString);
            var result = poster.Post(3);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                try
                {
                    var rowLength = newZoho[i].Row.ItemArray.Length;
                    var rowOffset = Math.Abs((int)newZoho[i][rowLength - 1])-1;

                    potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential.Rows[rowOffset]["ZohoID"] = ReadResult(result);
                    potentialTableAdapter.Update(potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential.Rows[rowOffset]);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to update: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The bit variable called poster works great. it returns a xml like result that has my zohoID which I parse out and try to store. For testing purposes I try to update only one record. I get the error with potentialTableAdapter.Update(potentialDatabaseDataSet). What is strange to me is that I use a very similar code to make a brand new record and it works great. Infact it is how I made the row with Soid = 1234. I am the only one that has access to this program and as far I know it is not multithreaded so I just don't understand why it is having concurrency issues. Please help :)

*EDIT*

Ok so I was playing around with it some and found that if I add a EndEdit to it I dont get the concurrent issue. On the flip side though Although my bound datagridview shows the updated data, the data doesn't actually get updated. So it's not that i'm back to square one I think i am actually rather close. I'm going from memory on this small bit of code so don't hate if it isn't right..it's mainly for an idea of what i'm talking about

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //emailRecord.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ZohoEmail.EmailExpectedShipping(emailRecord[i], "12/10/2012"))
            {//true means that the email went through just fine
                try
                {
                    var rowLengh = emailRecord[i].Row.ItemArray.Length;
                    var rowOffset = Math.Abs((int)emailRecord[i][rowLengh - 1]) - 1;

                    potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential.Rows[rowOffset][17] = true; //17 is Expected Email
                    potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential.Rows[rowOffset].AcceptChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to update: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
            potentialTableAdapter.Update(potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think i figured it out. Thank you very much Marcin for helping me so much on this problem of mine. You were right with the problem being in my generated table adapter. I ended up making my own based on what the autogenerated code was. Here is my code just incase anyone else is having problem with Autogenerated code.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;

namespace Zoho
{
    public partial class PotentialTableAdapter
    {
        SqlCeDataAdapter _adapter;
        SqlCeConnection _connection;
        SqlCeTransaction _transaction;
        SqlCeCommand[] _commandCollection;
        DataTable _table;

        public PotentialTableAdapter()
        {
            ClearBeforeFill = true;
            InitConnection();
            InitAdapter();
            InitCommandCollection();
            FillTable();
        }

        public bool ClearBeforeFill {get; set;}
        public SqlCeDataAdapter Adapter
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this._adapter == null))
                {
                    this.InitAdapter();
                }
                return this._adapter;
            }
        }
        public SqlCeConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                if (_connection == null)
                    InitConnection();
                return _connection;
            }
        }
        public SqlCeTransaction Transaction
        {
            get
            {
                return _transaction;
            }
            set
            {
                _transaction = value;
                for (int i = 0; (i < CommandCollection.Length); i = (i + 1))
                {
                    CommandCollection[i].Transaction = value;
                }
                Adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = value;
                Adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = value;
                Adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = value;
            }
        }
        public SqlCeCommand[] CommandCollection
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this._commandCollection == null))
                {
                    InitCommandCollection();
                }
                return this._commandCollection;
            }
        }
        public DataTable Table
        {
            get
            {
                if (_table == null)
                    FillTable();
                return _table;
            }
        }

    }
}
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Data;

namespace Zoho
{

    partial class PotentialTableAdapter
    {
                                    private void InitAdapter()
    {
        this._adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
        this._adapter.TableMappings.Add(GetTableMapping());
        this._adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Potential", Connection);
        this._adapter.InsertCommand = GetCommand(@"INSERT INTO [Potential] ([Soid], [SalesRep], [Account], [ClosingDate], [Amount], [Stage], [SourceId], [Product], [FirstName], [Email], [CustomerPO], [ZohoID], [WorkOrder], [ExpectedShip], [TrackingNumber], [DependencyID], [ProcessEmail], [ExpectedEmail], [ShippedEmail]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19)");
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand = GetCommand(@"UPDATE [Potential] SET [Soid] = @p1, [SalesRep] = @p2, [Account] = @p3, [ClosingDate] = @p4, [Amount] = @p5, [Stage] = @p6, [SourceId] = @p7, [Product] = @p8, [FirstName] = @p9, [Email] = @p10, [CustomerPO] = @p11, [ZohoID] = @p12, [WorkOrder] = @p13, [ExpectedShip] = @p14, [TrackingNumber] = @p15, [DependencyID] = @p16, [ProcessEmail] = @p17, [ExpectedEmail] = @p18, [ShippedEmail] = @p19 WHERE (([NCPotentialKey] = @p20))");
    }
                    private void InitConnection()
    {
        this._connection = new SqlCeConnection(Zoho.Properties.Settings.Default.PotentialDatabaseConnectionString);
    }
                        private void InitCommandCollection()
    {
        _commandCollection = new SqlCeCommand[1];
        _commandCollection[0] = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Potential", Connection);

    }
                        private void FillTable()
    {
        _table = new DataTable();
        Adapter.Fill(_table);
    }

                                                                                                                private DataTableMapping GetTableMapping()
    {
        var tableMapping = new DataTableMapping();

        tableMapping.SourceTable = "Table";
        tableMapping.DataSetTable = "Potential";
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Soid", "Soid");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("SalesRep", "SalesRep");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Account", "Account");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ClosingDate", "ClosingDate");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Amount", "Amount");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Stage", "Stage");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceId", "SourceId");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Product", "Product");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("FirstName", "FirstName");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "Email");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomerPO", "CustomerPO");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ZohoID", "ZohoID");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("WorkOrder", "WorkOrder");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ExpectedShip", "ExpectedShip");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("TrackingNumber", "TrackingNumber");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("DependencyID", "DependencyID");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ProcessEmail", "ProcessEmail");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ExpectedEmail", "ExpectedEmail");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ShippedEmail", "ShippedEmail");
        tableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("NCPotentialKey", "NCPotentialKey1");

        return tableMapping;

    }
                                            private SqlCeCommand GetDeleteCommand()
    {
        var deleteCommand = new SqlCeCommand();
        deleteCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
        deleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Potential] WHERE (([NCPotentialKey] = @p1))";
        deleteCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        var parameter = new SqlCeParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.Int, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, "NCPotentialKey", DataRowVersion.Original, null);
        deleteCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        return deleteCommand;
    }
        private SqlCeCommand GetCommand(string text)
        {
            var command = new SqlCeCommand(text);
            command.Connection = this.Connection;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.Int, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "Soid",          DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "SalesRep",      DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "Account",       DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "ClosingDate",   DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p5", SqlDbType.Money, 0,    ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "Amount",        DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p6", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "Stage",         DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p7", SqlDbType.Int, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "SourceId",      DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p8", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "Product",       DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p9", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "FirstName",     DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p10",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "Email",         DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p11",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "CustomerPO",    DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p12",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "ZohoID",        DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p13",SqlDbType.Int, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "WorkOrder",     DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p14",SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "ExpectedShip",  DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p15",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "TrackingNumber",DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p16",SqlDbType.Int, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "DependencyID",  DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p17",SqlDbType.Bit, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "ProcessEmail",  DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p18",SqlDbType.Bit, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "ExpectedEmail", DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p19",SqlDbType.Bit, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "ShippedEmail",  DataRowVersion.Current, null));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@p20",SqlDbType.Int, 0,      ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "NCPotentialKey",DataRowVersion.Original, null));

            return command;
        }
    }
}
```

now for my wrapper class. I find this to be rather useful to do it this way.
    using System;
    using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
    using System.Data;

```
namespace Zoho
{
    public class DatabaseConnection
    {
        PotentialTableAdapter table;
        public DatabaseConnection()
        {
            table = new PotentialTableAdapter();
        }
        public DataTable Table
        {
            get
            {
                return table.Table;
            }
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Attemping to update database: ");
                table.Adapter.Update(Table);
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fail: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and lastly for the snippet of code that actually matters. The one that Marcin helped me figure out. It is super easy actually.

```
        DatabaseConnection AllPotentials = new DatabaseConnection();
        var newZoho = AllPotentials.Table.DefaultView;
        var poster = new ZohoPoster(ZohoPoster.Fields.Potentials, zohoPoster.Calls.insertRecords);

        newZoho.RowFilter = "IsNull(ZohoID,'zoho') = 'zoho'";
        poster.Debugging = !UseZoho; //UseZoho= false which turns debugging on

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)//newZoho.Count; i++)
        {
            var xmlString = Potential.GetPotentialXML(newZoho[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending New Records to Zoho: {0}", xmlString);
            poster.PostItem.Set("xmlData", xmlString);
            var result = poster.Post(3);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                try
                {
                    newZoho[i].Row["ZohoID"] = ReadResult(result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to update: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Trying to update the database after getting zoho: ");
            AllPotentials.Update(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
```

I tried it out and it said success so i opened up the database in a different program and low and behold my fake data has the zoho id in it :) i'm so excited. Now I can actually get this program up and running. The only problem I am having now is that in my datagridview it is only showing like 4 or 5 records instead of 201 records (and i just thought about it i bet that filter has soemthign to do with it!). So well time to finish up my program now that it works! :) thank you again Marcin for being patient and helping me out. Since you told me that the problem was in my tableAdapter I am going to mark the question as answered by you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update only one row. Data adapter allows update of tables, not rows. So instead of

```
potentialTableAdapter.Update(potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential.Rows[rowOffset]);
```

use

```
potentialTableAdapter.Update(potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential);
```

**EDIT**

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here:

```
var rowLength = newZoho[i].Row.ItemArray.Length;
var rowOffset = Math.Abs((int)newZoho[i][rowLength - 1])-1;
```

It looks like you are getting number of columns first, which better would be:

```
var rowLength = potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential.Columns.Count;
```

then you counting row number based on value in last column and get row one before the value. This is what I don't understand why? Also you are counting row offset based on view.

Why you just don't use:

```
newZoho[i].Row["ZohoID"] = ReadResult(result);
potentialTableAdapter.Update(potentialDatabaseDataSet.Potential);
```

instead of counting which row you should update?

I believe *ZohoID* is foreign key which exists in database before update?

**EDIT 2**

I think the problem is with your automatic table adapter. First try tu update row in that in strong type way:

```
((PotentialRow)newZoho[i].Row).ZohoID = ReadResult(result);
```

And try to modify update query for your dataset adapter. Automatic data adapters generates very ugly queries. Change where clause in update query to compary only row **primary key** (ID) now all values.

Comment: Well I tried it in and out of the for loop and I am still getting the Concurrency Issue. I do have to say that I believe it is possible to update 1 row in that my table adapter gives me the option to for Update(DataRow row) and also (DataRow[] rows).

Comment: The reason that I was doing the row counting and so forth was that the last variable in the ItemArray was the row offset that that particular row came from in the entire table. In this case it was value was -21. Well obviously -21 is not a valid row in my database. So i counted from the first record down and it was 21 records to get to the newZoho[i] one. which means in a 0 based array I would have to make it 20. I didn't know about the column count bit. And that actually looks like it would work because it would return 11 and the row offset is in column 11 (on a zerobased array) so thank you

Comment: I just tried your idea and it gives me "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."  So i tried adding newZoho[i].Row.AcceptChanges() and EndEdit() then both and I still get a concurrent violation. I swear this is going to be the death of me. OH i almost forgot. ZohoID is a unique id that comes from a website after I commit that record to their database.

Comment: So you got me thinking about making my own table adapter. I've only been copying code and changing it that i want. Is this a dumb idea. When i looked at the update command it looks to be good in that it had "UPDATE [Potential] SET (all of my parameters) WHERE [NCPotentialKey] = @p20" So because it looks like ok to me it makes me want to make my own..and or not use one at all and figure out the grid view later